# How to disable pattern error message in the INPUT tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to request help on how can I disable the error message from the pattern tag.

As you know if you input a text that doesn't match the pattern this message will show "Please match the requested format."

**But I don't want to remove the pattern tag.**

I tried making the title tag empty but the error message still shows.

Even if they right a wrong code, I want the "Please match the requested format." to be displayed as none (display:none) with no space for the error message.

Hope you can understand my request.

```
<input title="" pattern="ABC|ABQ|ABW" type="text" name="CODES">
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, I understood correctly.

Set an empty string for the setCustomValidy.

```
<input type="text"
     pattern="ABC|ABQ|ABW"
     required="" 
     oninvalid="setCustomValidity(' ')"
      placeholder="Some text...maybe"  />
  </form>
```

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/i-empty/pen/abwwyBE)

Comment: The error message "Please match the requested format." still shows

Comment: @HarveyLinarez I'm not getting any errors in or outside of CodePen. Did you try CodePen or in your project?

Comment: @HarveyLinarez What method did you use?

Comment: @HarveyLinarez If my method worked please mark it as 'answer'.